# Should I crosspost this Arqade post?

Tags: discussion, question-appropriateness

As I have noticed that each stack community has their own nuances in what questions are well received by the community, I wanted to ask if [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247185/zen-bound-2-render-issue) is an acceptable crosspost.

Also the rational as to why it is a good or bad question.
I thought maybe someone on this exchange might know about where an APK or SDK for the game might be found. Maybe even I could try to fix it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's necessarily off-topic, but you're less likely to get a good answer here than there IMO.  It really should be a bug report.  The portion  asking whether anyone else has the issue would be off-topic (polling), but presumably you care about the solution more than the prevalence.  Asking where to find it would also be off-topic.